# How to force J to give error instead of incorrectly returning infinity?

Tags: j

If you instruct J to calculate a large result on a default precision noun, you quickly run into cases where it says the result is infinity `_`.  This is jarring because of what infinity means mathematically.

How can I instruct J to give errors instead of infinity when standard precision is exceeded?  Can I set this a default in my J installation?

e.g.

```
   !1000x  NB. Extended precision gives large finite result.
4023872600770937735437024339230039857193748642107146325437999104299385123986290205920442084869694048004799886101971960586316668729948085589013238296699445909974245040870737599188236277271887325197795059509952761208749754624970436014182780946464962910563938...

   !1000  NB. Default precision claims infinity. I'd generally prefer an error.
_
```

Comment: You can use [assert](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/29.htm) but why would you want to do that?

Comment: @eelvex Practically speaking, if I create and test a word, I don't want to use it in a more complex expression and find out that a slightly larger input value has caused a propagation of incorrect `_` results through the entire calculation.  Philosophically speaking, I want my programs to give correct results or refuse to run.

Comment: I'd say, then, that `assert` is the way to go.

Comment: I think if accuracy is the constraint then stay in extended precision and don't worry if regular precision returns infinity instead of a slightly smaller (though accurate) extended precision number that would avoid propagation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do what you're trying to do is redefine each primitive from which you want this behavior with an `assert.`. This will probably have performance implications.

```
   SafeFactorial =: 3 : 0
p =. ! y
assert. p < _
assert. p > __
p
)
   SafeFactorial 5
120
   SafeFactorial 50
3.04141e64
   SafeFactorial 500
|assertion failure: SafeFactorial
|   p<_
```

An important caveat from the comments:

> J is an array oriented language, and it's a rare circumstance where
>   one is operating only on a single number. Typically the input to
>   functions like factorial are arrays of multiple numbers, and so if you
>   design a function to throw an error like this, it will preclude you
>   from getting any results at all, even correct results if one atom is
>   bad.

Put a different way, the infinite result is often a desirable behavior when operating on arrays. You should consider carefully before introducing additional failure points.

Comment: I already added this comment to the other answer, but it's worth repeating here on this higher-voted one: this is certainly the way to achieve the effect OP asked for, but I'm not certain it's actually *desirable* from an operational perspective. J is an array oriented language, and it's a rare circumstance where one is operating only on a single number. Typically the input to functions like factorial are *arrays of multiple numbers*, and so if you design a function to throw an error like this, it will preclude you from getting any results at all, *even correct results* if **one** atom is bad.

Answer (score 4):

My goal was to get mathematically correct results.  I jumped to the conclusion that I should fail early instead of giving incorrect results as I would in Java. What I exactly asked for was covered by Dane and Eelvex and they deserve all credit for that.

Some observations though that might help others get in the J mindset:

Firstly, I was already aware of extended precision literals and became aware of the verb `x:` that converts integers to extended precision. If I want mathematically correct results by default I should get in the habit of using these things.

Secondly, I had already observed verbs like e.g. dyadic `i.` which return oversized results instead of failing. This is common in J and I should learn to filter results that I don't want instead of making my programs give errors all the time.

Answer (score 0):

This may not do exactly what you want because it uses the format foreign conjunction `8!:0` to change infinity to whatever you would like (including 'error'). Of course, it just looks like an error; what it is really doing is replacing `'_'` with `'error'` so it may not be what you want. The results are boxed strings as well, which may not fit your constraints.

```
   inf=: 'd<error>'&(8!:0)
   % i.6
_ 1 0.5 0.333333 0.25 0.2
   inf % i.6
┌─────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│error│1.000000000│0.500000000│0.333333333│0.250000000│0.200000000│
└─────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

More information can be found in the 8!: entry for foreign conjunctions in the J dictionary. http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx008.htm

Since your comment indicates you do actually want to trigger the error, you could use the assert. keyword to test the result for '_' before display but it is on a verb by verb basis and there is not a global setting that I know.

```
   9!:35 [ 1 NB. to set the assert. flag on
   test =: 3 : 0
​assert. _~:%y  NB. to see if _ shows up in the result of %y
​%y
​)
   test 1 + i.5
1 0.5 0.333333 0.25 0.2
   test  i.5
|assertion failure: test
|   _~:%y
```

Comment: To clarify, my intention is to have an actual error occur; a refusal to continue when it can't calculate correct results.  The formatting of infinity as `_` doesn't bother me.

Comment: @dukereg The problem with failing on `_` is that it will cause the *entire operation* to fail, meaning if you're `!`ing a 10x10 array, you won't get *any* results, even if only one number in that entire array is out of range.  In fact, this very observation is responsible for the general philosophy in J of communicating information via out-of-band return results (like infinity), rather than throwing errors.